# How to add line breaks to the specialties section of your LinkedIn profile

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters, newlines, social-networking, linkedin

How can we create line breaks in a way that they are respected by LinkedIn?

I'm using a Unix system (OS X).
I found [this answer](http://www.linkedin.com/answers/using-linkedIn/ULI/539227-3174277), but I think there has to be a way of doing it without running a Live CD.

Comment: Did anyone at least tried the Win version?

Comment: If it weren't for open bounties, I would vote to close this based on the fact that its off-topic / not programming related.  Perhaps the linked in support forums are a better place to try to solve this issue which is obviously some sort of input constraint applied by the website itself.

Comment: This is defo off topic and not programming related...voting to close as this should be filed under LinkedIn's own website as an issue there!

Comment: Agreed; this isn't programming related. It is **very** rare we do so, but I've revoked (refunded) the bounty. I'm moving it to superuser, where it *may* have a slightly better fit.

Comment: @Marc - it's about a web site, which **isn't** appropriate for Super User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If some people are reporting that it works on Linux, it's likely to be caused by the different line endings used by Windows.

At the end of a line:

- Windows uses carriage return, line feed (CRLF, `\r\n`)
- Linux uses line feed (LF, `\n`)
- Mac uses carriage return (CR, `\r`)

These are leftovers from ye olden days of computing, which, if you're really interested in it, you can read more about on [Wikipedia's newline article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Anyway, if you use a more powerful text editor on your Windows computer, many will have the option of converting line-breaks to the different styles. Just off the top of my head, [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/) and [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) are two free editors which can do this.

Comment: I'm actually using OSX.

Comment: @ozke - here are some links you might find useful then:
http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20001206164827794
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_end-of-line_format_for_dos-mac-unix
http://damonparker.org/blog/2006/01/05/convert-mac-line-endings/

Comment: It's worth noting that *old* Mac OS uses CR only. OS X and later uses LF, like the rest of the (non-Windows) world.

Answer (score -1):

I give nickf's answer as valid as I found it very useful. However, keep in mind what Jil McElroy says (in the link I originally posted).

> Be sure to review your Specialties in
>   the "View My Profile" tab. For some
>   reason, the "Edit my profile" tab does
>   not format line breaks correctly.